# Get the class of the Type that the Generic class is typed to

Tags: java, generics

If I have a generic class

say and I need to find out what the class is typed to .. how would I do that?

```
class Stack<T>{    
   public String getType(){
       // what can i write here to get the class name of T ?
   }
}
```